# How do I debug Visual Studio projects using VMware?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vmware

I just installed WMware Workstation for the first time, and noticed that it included some new toolbars in Visual Studio for me to be able to debug applications on a virtual machine.

Has anyone used this feature?  How do you use it, and what do you debug with it?
What are some of the benefits of debugging under a virtual machine as opposed to me just debugging it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find most of what you need to know here: http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2008/04/using-the-vmwar.html

The only benefit is testing your application on another OS. That or your code is so bad you're afraid to run it on your own computer for fear of destroying your system.

Comment: @Ryan: I take you've never had to test installs on various OSes with various patches, or QA in general...

Comment: I was thinking this would be a good way to test my mvc sites on IIS6 on Win2k3 .

Comment: @Ryan ...or the test team has a tough-to-repro bug in a VM. Debug on different configurations (not necessarily different OS).  

I used this all the time doing GINA development.  That had nothing to do with the quality of the code, and everything to do with a single bug rendering your machine unbootable.